# trusted certificate curl vs httpie

Tags: ssl, curl, ssl-certificate, httpie

trying to understand how to work around with self signed certificates. I am using vagrant ubuntu xenial box .After importing the ROOT certificate using method described in [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90450/adding-a-self-signed-certificate-to-the-trusted-list). To my surprised curl worked but httpie doesn't.

[image: dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates]

```
 curl  -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"Joseph","sname":"adfadf"}' https://x.x.x.x/test.php

echo '{"name":"Joseph","sname":"adfadf"}' | http POST  https://x.x.x.x/test.php

http: error: SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='x.x.x.x', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /test.php (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)'),)) while doing POST request to URL: https://x.x.x.x/test.php
```

However when I use the --verify option of httpie it worked. But that's a bit against the method of trusting the certificate on the server that making the call to the API.

Is there anything I am not doing well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much googlefu, it turns out it's a bug under the [httpie github page](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie/issues/480). It started working when I swapped the pip installation with an apt-get installation of httpie